# Is being worried in bad omens shirk

Tags: allah, sin, shirk

I start to worry am I commiting shirk if I’m worried please help please respond tho I don’t act or speak upon it I try to say to myself it’s fake it’s not real. I also heard a sheikh say that as human beings we can’t help ourselves from having this feeling but Allah cures it through tawakkul. I don’t wanna keep having these thoughts because it may lead to shirk. I have the feeling that this could be waswas am I held accountable.

Comment: Why are you worried?

Comment: Mainly doubts on it and shirk idk I’m worried that if I commited shirk

Comment: Why do you think that you are doing shirk?

Comment: Because I have doubts on bad omens isint that kinda believing in it?

Comment: Bro, do you believe in that?

Comment: If doubts and being worried don’t count then no I don’t necessarily do but every time I watch like a cute black cat video i just get doubts and I don’t know I don’t click of the video because that’s pretty much you believing in it

Comment: What type of believe brother, Please clear it I don't understand.

Comment: If you believe in something it means you know that it's 100 percent true

Comment: I don’t know how to explain I just have doubts and worry if while I worry if I believe in it I’m uncertain pretty much and I do not actually believe in it I’m just worried if having these doubts is believing in it.

Comment: Ok I do not believe it’s 100 percent trust just doubts that I can tell u

Comment: Don't worry it's not believing, whenever these thoughts come to your mind immediately start thinking about something else

Comment: Okay thank you I just wanted to know if I were committing shirk now I’m calm :)

Comment: Here's my utube channel link, please subscribe it- https://youtube.com/channel/UCzCxGaMEv3U2WlmqoCjH-8w